# SupportedOrientations unavailable in XAML of windows phone 8.1 app?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

What is the equivalent of this in Windows Phone 8.1 App.  When I create a new app, there is no more phone:ApplicationPage

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
...
...
SupportedOrientations="Landscape" Orientation="LandscapeLeft"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, In windows phone 8.1, We can't set supportedOrientations in page's XAML. We can set supportedOrientations of App in Package.appxmanifest only.

Comment: Again something that Microsoft just forgot when porting Windows Phone Silverlight to Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT. We can only lock the complete application, not a single page. Great.

Answer (score 8):

You can force the orientation of any page via code, writing just after the this.InitializeComponent():

```
DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape;
```

or

```
DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped;
```

or

```
DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Portrait;
```

Comment: This is an approach but it locks the rotation for the whole application. If only one page should be locked AutoRotationPreferences must be reset in OnNavigatedFrom.

Comment: @JürgenBayer It doesn't work for me. The orientation isn't locked :(