# Force the App to become on Portrait View when clicking a Button

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, screen-orientation

On a certain `ButtonClick` event, I need the app to turn to `Portrait View` even if the user is holding it in the `Landscape View`. The `ApplicationView` only has a `GetForCurrentView().Orientation` string, not a Set. How can this be possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i set PageOrientation.Landscape in programmatically? Windows Phone 8 C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577709/how-do-i-set-pageorientation-landscape-in-programmatically-windows-phone-8-c-sh)

Comment: There's also a related question using [DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24827697/how-to-set-supported-orientations-property-in-windows-phone-8-1)

Comment: Nope! In Windows 8.1 `this.SupportedOrientations` and `this.Orientation` don't exist...

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144735/change-orientation-of-windows-8-1-desktop-from-c-sharp-wpf) might help

Comment: Looking further, [it seems it's possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507672/supportedorientations-unavailable-in-xaml-of-windows-phone-8-1-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it is impossible to Set the Application to a certain `ApplicationView`, `Portrait` or `Landscape` without physically turning the device. I tried to trick the user by rotating my image (by animating it in Blend) to look like it's in a `Portrait` View. The user will then return the device in his hands.